# How can I see how many messages I sent across all Discord servers?

Tags: discord

My Discord username is `franckdernoncourt`. I can use `from:franckdernoncourt` to see how many messages I sent in one Discord server. But how can I see how many messages I sent across all Discord servers?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with any of the apps (web or otherwise). It's also not possible to do with a regular bot, unless you can add it to every server you have access to, with the same viewing permissions. You'll probably have to use some sort of userscript (or a bot empowered to act on the behalf of your account, if that's even possible).

Comment: @Laurel thanks, looks like no easy solution indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2573#issuecomment-816993986) to [night](https://github.com/night) (Discord former employee), it is not possible to see how many messages one has sent across all Discord servers:

> Due to how Discord stores messages internally (we operate a large scale distributed system) we have no way of retrieving a count of messages for a channel or a user.